# How to change the default Wordpress upload folder to a shared network one?

Tags: wordpress, path, upload, unc

I have a webserver setup in 2 separate pc's .

First machine holds the MySql server and folder for uploads, shared on the network, that i can access using UNC path like `//PC1/uploads`.

Second machine holds the ISS server and the Wordpress files.
I can use `file://` to embed existing images, etc from the first machine in the wordpress site.

What I don't know is how to setup Wordpress to change it's default upload folder to `//PC1/uploads` instead of the default local folder.

I have tried with `define('UPLOADS','file://PC1/uploads');` and with a ftp server

```
define ('UPLOADS','ftp://User:pass@pc1.ip');
```

I get and error `Is its parent directory writable by the server?`
The upload folder has Everyone read/write in permisions setting , and I can use `mput` to upload files with ftp.

Thank you

Comment: change the wp-content, uploads folder - http://www.kvcodes.com/2013/12/rename-wp-content-folder-and-uploads-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was really simple.
Move the entire webroot on the shared folder, set the UNC path and credentials in ISS and `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR,'\\\\ServerName\\SharedFolder\\'.'/wp-content');`

Answer (score 0):

The above answer isn't exactly right for WordPress 4.7. I got it with including both the following in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR','//server/sharedpath'.'/wp-content');
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://url-to-virtual-directory/wp-content' );
```